# Finding pairwise overlap in columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
| FName | F1 |  F2 | F3| 
| A     | 0  |  1  | 1 |
| B     | 1  |  0  | 1 |
| C     | 1  |  0  | 0 |
| D     | 1  |  1  | 1 |
```

From here I need to find the count of pairwise set intersection for each of the columns, i.e F1-F2 is 1 , F1-F3 is 2, F2-F3 is 2 and so on.

One obvious method is to convert each series into the `set` datastructure and then take set intersection followed by length of the resulting set. But is there way in pandas by which the same can be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `FName` as index, and then use matrix multiplication (assume you have only 1 and 0 here and you want to count overlap of both 1s):

```
df.set_index("FName", inplace=True)
df.T.dot(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy` broadcasting with `bool`

```
d1 = df.set_index('FName')
v = d1.values.astype(bool)
pd.DataFrame(
    (v.reshape(4, 1, 3) & v.reshape(4, 3, 1)).sum(0),
    d1.columns, d1.columns
)

    F1  F2  F3
F1   3   1   2
F2   1   2   2
F3   2   2   3
```

---

Or using `np.einsum` to perform the dot product

```
d1 = df.set_index('FName')
v = d1.values

pd.DataFrame(
    np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', v.T, v),
    d1.columns, d1.columns
)


    F1  F2  F3
F1   3   1   2
F2   1   2   2
F3   2   2   3
```

---

Equivalently with `np.dot`

```
d1 = df.set_index('FName')
v = d1.values

# python 3 should be able to do `v.T @ v`
pd.DataFrame(
    v.T.dot(v),
    d1.columns, d1.columns
)
```

***time testing***

[image]